# Prove if $A_1\supset A_2,A_1; A_2\in \Im$ then $\Pr(A_1)>\Pr(A_2)$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(S,\Im,P(\cdot))$ be a probability space where $\Im$ is a field denoting a collection of subsets of $S$. How can I prove that

If $A_1\supset A_2, A_1,A_2\in \Im$ then \begin{equation*} \Pr(A_1)>\Pr(A_2)\end{equation*}

Actually the only thing I find troublesome is the strict inequality, because I can prove if it if was $\Pr(A_1)\geq \Pr(A_2)$ using the axiom that $\Pr(A_i)\geq 0$ for all $i$. After I have shown that $\Pr(A_1)\geq \Pr(A_2)$ how can I show the strict inequality?

Comment: Is this a problem (e.g. from a book) that you are solving, or one that you made up yourself?  Do you know about _events of probability_ $0$ (other than the empty set) that can exist in some sigma-fields?

Comment: it is not true.

Comment: Do you have any additional information on $S$? Also, is $A_2$ a proper subset of $A_1$?

Comment: No extra information on $S$ is given. It's a problem on a practice sheet. The intended solution problem probably only has me show that $\Pr(A_1)\geq\Pr(A_2)$. Some confusion may also have arisen from the interpretation of $\sup$ which I interpret to mean a proper supserset, and I thought that with this interpretation somehow I might be able to show the strict inequality.

Comment: Please improve the title of your question.

Comment: Even that $A\subset B$, $A\ne B$, does not imply that $P(A)\lt P(B)$.